# How to append a sting and a variable in BASH

Tags: bash

I have a variable that points at a file called point.c

I would like to temporarily append "A" to "_SRCS" so I can rename the variable and use it in a function as "SRCS".

```
A_SRCS=point.c
  
pro="A B"
for x in $pro
    do
    SRCS=${${x}"_SRCS"}
    echo $SRCS #(will point to a function later on..)
    done
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to ask. You can copy the value of one variable into another and you can delete the original, but this makes little sense to want.

Comment: I am actually trying to append a variable with a string - "x" being the variable from the for loop and the "_SRCS" as a string

Comment: the end result is that every iteration the variable $SRCS is  pointing at another file. I forgot to add that i will have also "B_SRCS" and "C_SRCS"

Comment: Vaguely sounds like the duplicate is correct then. @oguz congrats for the gold badge!

Comment: @tripleee Thanks! Not sure if there's a better dupe for this, but I'm sure this has been asked several times before

Comment: @tripleee - Congrats !!! so i did mange to do this SRCS="${x}_SRCS" but I am not able to use "A_SRCS" as a variable

Comment: Did you notice the `!` for indirection?

Comment: YESSSSS got it ! I am a 40y/o musician from TLV doing a career shift due to the corona virus. Help is super appreciated !